# How to solve this error in code of batch programming?

Tags: batch-file

I am tring to make substring of string and print it in cmd but unable to do it.

```
set p=mnopq
for /L %a in (1,1,5) Do (
   set q=%p:~%%a%,1
   echo %q%
)
```

But it is giving error please help me to troubleshoot this.thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

That would require *Delayed Expansion* feature via `SETLOCAL` (see `cmd /?` help to usage). The reason it doesn't work as expected is because the commands following the `for` command are treated as parameters, so any `%` based variables will be expanded immediately except the one used for the `for` command.

Here's the corrected batch commands.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set p=mnopq
for /L %%a in (1,1,5) Do (
  set q=!p:~%%a,1!
  echo !q!
)
```